# Creating a transparent RichTextBox with Visual C++

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++

I'm looking to find a way to make a transparent RichTextBox in Visual C++. I've searched everywhere, the forums and the net but nothing seems to work. 99% of what I've found is in VB and C# which I can't seem to convert either.

Comment: Winforms isn't a thing in c++, so C# answers can't be 'converted'. Either use MFC or something a bit friendlier like Qt. There are lots of tutorials for both out there.

Comment: When you _create_ the control, you must specify the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` extended style (`GWL_EXSTYLE`), and also supply a `WM_ERASEBKGND` event handler in your message loop.